# How to calculate a factorial using a for loop and print the calculation with the answer?

Tags: python, for-loop, factorial

I'm trying to work out how to print the full breakdown of a factorial in Python, eg. `4 x 3 x 2 x 1 = 24`. I have been instructed that I must use a `for` loop. 
I got close to it a while ago, but then did some stupid stuff and lost it again.

Here is my code so far:

```
number = int(input("Please enter a number: "))
factorial = 1

for product in range(1, number + 1):
    if number > 0:
        factorial = factorial * number
        number = number - 1
    print(product, "x", number, "\t= ", factorial)
```

Comment: This code works for me. What problems are you having?

Comment: It doesn't work, it's off-by-one on the RHS of the multiplication @JETM (at least in terms of the print-out)

Comment: If I enter 4, the output says 1 x 3 = 4 , 2 x 2 = 12 , 3 x 1 = 24 , 4 x 0 = 24     Now I'm not that great at maths, but i don't thing that's right.

Comment: Bah, no, the problem is worse than I originally saw. Deleted answer.

Comment: "the full breakdown of a factorial", in this case, would mean an input of `4` would give `4 x 3 x 2 x 1 = 24`, and the input _isn't_ `24` in this case and working backwards, right?

Comment: roganjosh, yes that's right, the input is 4 not 24. something is definitely going backwards, i just can't figure out what it is, nor can i figure out how to output a one line answer instead of 4 separate sums (using 4 as an example)

Comment: For fun you could do something like `' x '.join(str(n) for n in range(n,0,-1)) + ' = ' + str(math.factorial(n))`, though it doesn't use an explicit for loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
number = int(input("Please enter a number: "))
factorial = 1
for product in range(number, 1, -1):
    factorial *= product
    print(product, 'x', end=' ')
print(1, '=', factorial)
```

Comment: Daniel Mesejo! You are an angel!!!!!! Thank you! That works beautifully!